# Updating Sqlite3 colomn, key match issue

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I know that this is a silly questiong, but how are you meant to update a column by matching it to its key in sqlite, I am trying this method but I keep getting no matches, I know that the keys should match up as I got them from the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
c.execute('''SELECT ROUND(AVG(ft.score), 2), st.subreddit_id
         FROM posts as ft JOIN subreddits as st ON st.subreddit_id == ft.subreddit_id
         GROUP BY 2
         ORDER BY 2 desc
         ''')

average = []
for rows in c.fetchall():
    average.append(rows)

for index in average:
    start = time.time()
    print(index)
    try:
         c.execute('''UPDATE subreddits SET average_score = ''' + str(index[0]) + ''' WHERE ''' + str(index[1]) + ''' == subreddit_id;''')
         print(str(index[1]))
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        print('{} not found'.format(index))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your parameters as the second argument to `.execute()` to allow sqlite3 to do the proper escaping. You also had a syntax error `==`. Try this:

```
c.execute('''UPDATE subreddits 
             SET average_score = ? WHERE ? = subreddit_id;''', (index[0],index[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a silly thing to get caught on